# How do I hid the UITabBarView when loading some view?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an iPhone app, where I have a UITabBarController that has a UINavigationController for each TabBarItem.

I want, after some level of navigation, to hide the TabBar, and to replace it with a full screen view, just like the iPod application, the TabBar hides when you reach the media player, and returns when you get back to the playlist or whatever.

Any help or thoughts is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the new viewController's `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed:`-property. That will hide the current `UITabBar` when you send the `[navController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]`-function.
It will also reappear when you pop the viewController.